# Executing function onclick when function is in document.ready

Tags: javascript, function, canvas

I'm fairly new to Javascript so I was hoping for a bit of help. I've been playing with animating a graph using canvas and javascript. I have it so that when the page loads, it will fill up the graph to a pre-determined percentage.

I also have some buttons that have an onclick on them, and the aim is for clicking these buttons to execute the animating function again but with a different percentage. However, clicking on them doesn't so a thing.

Any help you could give me on this would be great.

Code:

```
    window.onload = function(){
    //canvas initialization
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //dimensions
    var W = canvas.width;
    var H = canvas.height;
    //Variables
    var degrees = 0;
    var new_degrees = 0;
    var difference = 0;
    var color = "#c70505"; //green looks better to me
    var bgcolor = "#222";
    var text;
    var animation_loop, redraw_loop;

    function init()
    {
        //Clear the canvas everytime a chart is drawn
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);

        //Background 360 degree arc
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = bgcolor;
        ctx.lineWidth = 30;
        ctx.arc(W/2, H/2, 100, 0, Math.PI*2, false); //you can see the arc now
        ctx.stroke();

        //gauge will be a simple arc
        //Angle in radians = angle in degrees * PI / 180
        var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.lineWidth = 30;
        //The arc starts from the rightmost end. If we deduct 90 degrees from the angles
        //the arc will start from the topmost end
        ctx.arc(W/2, H/2, 100, 0 - 90*Math.PI/180, radians - 90*Math.PI/180, false); 
        //you can see the arc now
        ctx.stroke();

        //Lets add the text
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.font = "50px bebas";
        text = Math.floor(degrees/360*100) + "%";
        //Lets center the text
        //deducting half of text width from position x
        text_width = ctx.measureText(text).width;
        //adding manual value to position y since the height of the text cannot
        //be measured easily. There are hacks but we will keep it manual for now.
        ctx.fillText(text, W/2 - text_width/2, H/2 + 15);
    }

    function draw(percent)
    {
        //Cancel any movement animation if a new chart is requested
        if(typeof animation_loop != undefined) clearInterval(animation_loop);

        //random degree from 0 to 360
        new_degrees = percent
        difference = new_degrees - degrees;
        //This will animate the gauge to new positions
        //The animation will take 1 second
        //time for each frame is 1sec / difference in degrees
        animation_loop = setInterval(animate_to, 1000/difference);
    }

    //function to make the chart move to new degrees
    function animate_to()
    {
        //clear animation loop if degrees reaches to new_degrees
        if(degrees == new_degrees) 
            clearInterval(animation_loop);

        if(degrees < new_degrees)
            degrees++;
        else
            degrees--;

        init();
    }

        draw(100);

}

<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>


<button onclick="draw(360)">100%</button>
<button onclick="draw(270)">75%</button>
```

Comment: uhm, your title seems very different from your problem.

Comment: Clicking on the buttons doesn't re seem to execute the draw function again and re-animate the graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `draw` function is out of scope as soon as the anonymous function you have assigned to `window.onload` finishes executing.  If you declare the functions in the global scope instead, you'll be able to call them anywhere.  Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ne9Bq/).

Answer (score 0):

Try my update:

```
<script>
//canvas initialization
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
//dimensions
var W = canvas.width;
var H = canvas.height;
//Variables
var degrees = 0;
var new_degrees = 0;
var difference = 0;
var color = "#c70505"; //green looks better to me
var bgcolor = "#222";
var text;
var animation_loop, redraw_loop;

function init()
{
    //Clear the canvas everytime a chart is drawn
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);

    //Background 360 degree arc
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = bgcolor;
    ctx.lineWidth = 30;
    ctx.arc(W/2, H/2, 100, 0, Math.PI*2, false); //you can see the arc now
    ctx.stroke();

    //gauge will be a simple arc
    //Angle in radians = angle in degrees * PI / 180
    var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineWidth = 30;
    //The arc starts from the rightmost end. If we deduct 90 degrees from the angles
    //the arc will start from the topmost end
    ctx.arc(W/2, H/2, 100, 0 - 90*Math.PI/180, radians - 90*Math.PI/180, false); 
    //you can see the arc now
    ctx.stroke();

    //Lets add the text
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.font = "50px bebas";
    text = Math.floor(degrees/360*100) + "%";
    //Lets center the text
    //deducting half of text width from position x
    text_width = ctx.measureText(text).width;
    //adding manual value to position y since the height of the text cannot
    //be measured easily. There are hacks but we will keep it manual for now.
    ctx.fillText(text, W/2 - text_width/2, H/2 + 15);
}

function draw(percent)
{
    //Cancel any movement animation if a new chart is requested
    if(typeof animation_loop != undefined) clearInterval(animation_loop);

    //random degree from 0 to 360
    new_degrees = percent
    difference = new_degrees - degrees;
    //This will animate the gauge to new positions
    //The animation will take 1 second
    //time for each frame is 1sec / difference in degrees
    animation_loop = setInterval(animate_to, 1000/difference);
}

//function to make the chart move to new degrees
function animate_to()
{
    //clear animation loop if degrees reaches to new_degrees
    if(degrees == new_degrees) 
        clearInterval(animation_loop);

    if(degrees < new_degrees)
        degrees++;
    else
        degrees--;

    init();
}
draw(100);
</script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<button onclick="draw(360)">100%</button>
<button onclick="draw(270)">75%</button>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. I tried putting it all in one function and then calling that function but it didn't work